# Psql could not connect to server: No such file or directory, 5432 error?

Tags: postgresql, vagrant

I'm trying to run `psql` on my Vagrant machine, but I get this error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory

Is the server running locally and accepting connections on 
Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Note: Vagrant 1.9.2
Box: ubuntu/trusty64, https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64

**EDIT**
Commands I've used in order to install and run postgres:

- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install postgresql`
- `sudo su postgres`
- `psql -d postgres -U postgres`

Comment: This was the answer that worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/824325/733901

Answer (score 258, accepted):

I've had this same issue, related to the configuration of my pg_hba.conf file (located in `/etc/postgresql/9.6/main`). Please note that 9.6 is the postgresql version I am using.

The error itself is related to a misconfiguration of postgresql, which causes the server to crash before it starts.

I would suggest following these instructions:

1. Certify that postgresql service is running, using `sudo service postgresql start`
2. Run `pg_lsclusters` from your terminal
3. Check what is the cluster you are running, the output should be something like:

   Version - Cluster   Port Status Owner    Data directory

   9.6  -------  main --   5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main

   > Disregard the '---' signs, as they are being used there only for alignment.
   >   The important information are the version and the cluster. You can also check whether the server is running or not in the status column.
4. Copy the info from the version and the cluster, and use like so: 
   `pg_ctlcluster <version> <cluster> start`, so in my case, using version 9.6 and cluster 'main', it would be `pg_ctlcluster 9.6 main start`
5. If something is wrong, then postgresql will generate a log, that can be accessed on `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-<version>-main.log`, so in my case, the full command would be `sudo nano /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.6-main.log`.
6. The output should show what is the error.

   > 2017-07-13 16:53:04 BRT [32176-1] LOG:  **invalid authentication method "all"**
   >   
   >  2017-07-13 16:53:04 BRT [32176-2] **CONTEXT:  line 90 of configuration file "/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf"**
   >   
   >  2017-07-13 16:53:04 BRT [32176-3] FATAL:  could not load pg_hba.conf
7. Fix the errors and restart postgresql service through `sudo service postgresql restart` and it should be fine.

I have searched a lot to find this, credit goes to this [post](http://www.postgresql-archive.org/Erro-de-conexao-com-o-postgresql-td2048576.html#a2048587).

Best of luck!

Comment: Excellent guide. Full of comprehensive explanations !

Comment: For step 4, I had to do `sudo systemctl start postgresql@9.5-main` instead of `pg_ctlcluster 9.5 main start`. Thank you for your awesome explanation!

Comment: on mine, I can not run this: "pg_ctlcluster 10 main start"
instead this work for me: "/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_ctl restart -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main"

of course you should point to your own postgre version and path.

I forgot where did I get this solution, but it's on my terminal's history. May be someone need it. 

thank you for this answer, this lead me to the right direction.

Comment: Running `pg_ctlcluster` as the postgres user gave me the error message I needed directly. Better than `sudo pg_ctlcluster` for me. But I am running Postgres 12 or 13.

Answer (score 62):

## I had the same issue but non of the answers here helped.

#### How I fixed it (mac)

- Try to start postgresql with `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start`
- Look for the **Error Message** that says something like `FATAL: could not open directory "pg_tblspc": No such file or directory`.
- Create that missing directory `mkdir /usr/local/var/postgres/pg_tblspc`
- Repeat from step one until you created all missing directories
- When done and then trying to start postgresql again it *might* say `FATAL: lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists`
- Delete **postmaster.pid**: `rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid`
- Start postgres with: `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start`
- Done ✨

Answer (score 60):

These two steps solved it for me on Mac:

```
rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid
brew services restart postgresql
```

For M1 Macs:

```
rm /opt/homebrew/var/postgres/postmaster.pid
brew services restart postgresql
```

In case you face this issue (reported by @luckyguy73): `psql: FATAL: database "postgresql" does not exist`

You can run

```
brew postgresql-upgrade-database
```

to fix it.

Comment: thanks man, i went from a can't connect to a fatal by following your instructions: "psql: FATAL:  database "postgresql" does not exist"

Comment: Huh weird, this always works for me. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: no worries, it actually turned out ok.  i just ran 'brew postgresql-upgrade-database' and that did the trick, thanks

Comment: Glad you fixed it! If you don't mind I'll add that to the answer too, in case someone else faces the same issue. Thanks

Comment: After a power outage, I always have this problem on my dev Mac.
Removing the .pid file always worked for me, in my case it's: `rm /usr/local/var/postgresql@9.6/postmaster.pid`

Comment: This was it for me - how to recover after a crash.

Comment: I've had the same problem as mentioned @balazs630. After a power outage, I had to `rm /usr/local/var/postgresql@9.6/postmaster.pid`. Thanks a million @balaz630!

Answer (score 24):

I am just posting this for anyone who is feeling lost and hopeless as I did when I found this question. It seems that sometimes by editing some psotgresql-related config files, one can accidentally change the permissions of the file:

[image]

Note how pg_hba.conf belongs to root, and users cannot even read it. This causes postgres to not be able to open this file and therefore not be able to start the server, throwing the error seen in the original question.

By running

```
sudo chmod +r pg_hba.conf
```

I was able to make this file once again accessible to the postgres user and then after running

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

Was able to get the server running again.

Comment: Yes, this was my problem, and this was not pointed out in logs (or if it was I didn't understood as it).

Comment: Not exactly what happened to me, but for some reason NETWORK SERVICE lost write privileges to the entire directory structure. This answer pointed me in the right direction hence the upvote.

Answer (score 8):

**WARNING: This will remove the database**

Use command:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres && initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8
```

Comment: Doesn't this remove entire database? I think that a word of warning would be in order.

Comment: Thanks @Tucker Watts and @Gaurav Verma. I solved my problem by trying both solutions and added this command `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l logfile start`.

Answer (score 7):

**WARNING: This will remove the database**

Within zsh:

```sh
rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres && initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8
```

This is the only thing that worked for me after countless hours trouble shooting.

Answer (score 7):

This works for me:

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgresql@9.6 stop;
brew services stop postgresql@9.6;
brew services start postgresql@9.6;
```

Answer (score 6):

Does the `/etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf` show that port being assigned? On my default Xubuntu Linux install, mine showed port = 5433 for some reason as best as I can remember, but I did comment out the line in that same file that said `listen_addresses = 'localhost'` and uncommented the line `listen_addresses = '*'`. So maybe start and check there. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to solve the issue by running:

```
sudo systemctl start postgresql@9.5-main
```

Comment: `sudo systemctl start postgresql@12-main` worked for me

Answer (score 5):

In my case Postgres was managed through Homebrew Services (i.e. started via `brew services start postgresql@10` Terminal command for the Postgres 10 that I use), and for that setup I had to discover a couple of essential steps to do before I could apply any advice in this thread. So I want to share just that piece as it may help someone who has the same setup.

NOTE: all the commands below are to be run in Terminal.

To give a quick background: After upgrading to macOS Big Sur I discovered that Postgres wasn't working and running `psql` results in the error mentioned in the original question above. I tried to start Postgres (via the `brew services start postgresql@10` command), this resulted in a message `Service postgresql@10 already started`. If I tried to restart it (via the `brew services restart postgresql@10`) I got a message that it was stopped and then started **successfully**. But! This was a misleading message, and I spent quite some time searching for config issues etc. before discovering that the service was not started successfully in reality.

So, the way to investigate this is:

1. Make sure the service is started by running the `brew services start postgresql@10` (the latter argument may be different depending on what your Homebrew package name is e.g. `postgresql@12` or plain `postgresql`).
2. Run `brew services list`. This is the command that gives you **the true state** of the service. In my case it said that Postgres' status is error:

`Name         Status  User  Plist
postgresql@10 error   Denis /Users/Denis/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@10.plist
redis         started Denis /Users/Denis/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.redis.plist`

3. To investigate further open the config shown in the same command output in Plist column (I used `nano /Users/Denis/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@10.plist` to check it).
4. In the config look for the `StandardErrorPath` key, and open the file located in the value of that key, i.e. in the `<string>` tag following the key. In my case it was `/usr/local/var/log/postgresql@10.log`.
5. Open that log and check the latest error (I used `nano /usr/local/var/log/postgresql@10.log` and then `Alt+/` to go to the end of the file).
6. Voila. That is the *real* error to investigate, which you can then look for in the previous answers or google for. I'm not covering the rest here, as the goal of this answer is to show how to find the real error if you use Homebrew Services to run Postgres. (In my case it was the `lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists` already covered in the previous answers, plus the path to check right in the error message, in my case `/usr/local/var/postgresql@10`).

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't connect using the `psql` command and kept getting the error Cannot connect to Server: No such file or directory.

**Step 1: Check the status of the Postgres cluster**

> `$ pg_lsclusters`

**Step 2: Restart the Postgres cluster**

> `$ sudo pg_ctlcluster 12 main start`

*Make sure to replace 12 with your version of Postgres*

**Step 3: Check again and connect**

> `$ pg_lsclusters`

> `$ sudo -i -u postgres`

> `$ psql`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was the lockfile `postmaster.id` that was not deleted properly during the last system crash that caused the issue. Deleting it with `sudo rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid` and restarting Postgres solved the problem.

Comment: This comment was so helpful to tracking the issue down. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

just reinstall your pgsql with direct version sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.5 (u must remove the package before install new one)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you should clarify port that postgres.
In my case I didn't know which port postgres was running on.

```
lsof -i | grep 'post'
```

then you can know which port is listening.

```
psql -U postgres -p "port_in_use"
```

with port option, might be answer. you can use psql.

Answer (score 3):

I occasionally have the same issue but mostly after macOS upgrades. Shutting down and migrating to the new version usually fixes it for me(make changes according to your version). So first upgrade your postgresql

```
brew services stop postgresql@12
brew services start postgresql@12
brew postgresql-upgrade-database
```

This is mostly a temporary fix but since I couldn't find a better solution this works for me.

Update: If the issue says that another postmaster is running then try removing it from that location(your postmaster.pid location will be displayed to you)

`rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid`

Comment: brew postgresql-upgrade-database is what finally worked for me after i tried everything else

Comment: hmn. this works for me as well although I don't have any db installed from the previous version. weird.

Answer (score 3):

If non of the above answers are not working for you, then please try this one,

Many people have mentioned many solutions to this problem! But all of them forgot that, the same problem will arise when your disk don't have enough space or the space you are assigned for `postgres` is full

> Check your system storage, if its full free up some space! then restart your postgres by `sudo service postgresql restart` or do a stop and start `sudo service posgresql stop` then `sudo service postgresql start`

This will solve the issue, it solved for me

Answer (score 3):

> Ubuntu 20

This Problem happened to me, as ubuntu pre-installed version of Postgresql-9.6 server was always down and after trying all the above answers it didn't start.

Solution:

1. I installed another version of Postgresql which is postgresql-13, using this command: `sudo apt install postgresql` it will install the latest version of postgresql.
2. I see if the server is `online` or `down` using this command: `pg_lsclusters`[image: server_status] if the new version of postgresql is `online`, we will proceed to remove the `old` version of postgresql.
3. we will see all packages that are installed related to postgresql, using this command: `dpkg -l | grep postgresql`[image: see postgresql insalled packages]
4. Remove the `old version`, which is here `postgresql-9.6`. Using this command:
   `sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql-9.6 postgresql-client-9.6` replace `9.6` with your old version number. Final remaining packages related to the `latest Version 13`:
   [image]
5. Restart your postgresql latest version server, which is here `postgresql-13`. Using this command: `sudo systemctl restart postgresql@13-main` replace `13` in the command with your latest version number.
6. Now, if you try `psql` command you will get an error related to your user, as in the image:[image: user fatal]
7. To Remove the above error, The installation procedure created a user account called postgres that is associated with the default Postgres role, to switch over to the postgres account use this command: `sudo -u postgres psql` this command will log you into the interactive Postgres session. You can also set your password for this user using this command `\password postgres`.

   [image: postgresql session]
8. Then change the `Port` to the `deafult port of postgresql`, which is `5432` as all application will try to connect to postgresql using this port by default, using this command: `sudo nano /etc/postgresql/13/main/postgresql.conf`, it will open postgresql configuration file, then search for `port` and change it to `5432`. After that you need to restart the server using this command `sudo systemctl restart postgresql@13-main`. Note, Replace `13` in the command with your latest version.

> If you want to create your own User/Role, use this command: `sudo -u postgres createuser --interactive`. The script will prompt you with some choices, as in the `image` and based on your responses, it will execute the correct Postgres commands to create a user to your specifications.
> [image: prompt to create new role]

[Tutorial: For more information on postgresql related commands](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-postgresql-on-ubuntu-20-04-quickstart)

Comment: Failed to restart postgres@12-main.service: Unit postgres@12-main.service not found

Comment: @AlxVallejo you may removed something that's related to postgres-12, please remove all things that have `-oldVersionNumber` in it only. I updated my answer and `put an image in step 4` to the available packages after you remove the old packages related to old postgresql installation.

Comment: I honestly didn't need any of this except your last step. As well as making sure the config files were owned by postgres `chmod postgres:postgres` on the config files. Normal service restart and everything worked.

Comment: @AlxVallejo if the answer solved a part from your problem, please upvote the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Open your database manager and execute this script

```
update pg_database set datallowconn = 'true' where datname = 'your_database_name';
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error when I create the SQL db in a VM. I had changed the default value of /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf `shared_buffers = 200MB` to 75% of my total RAM. Well, I forgot to actually allocate that RAM in the VM. When I gave the command to make a new database, I received the same error.

Powered off, gave the baby its bottle (RAM) and presto, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

The same thing happened to me as I had changed something in the `/etc/hosts` file. After changing it back to `127.0.0.1 localhost` it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I restored my database from last pg_basebackup backup file. After that when I tried to connect database(psql), I was getting the same error. The error was resolved, when I updated pg_hba.conf file and wherever "peer" authentication was there I replaced that with "md5" and then restarted postgres services. After that, the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

This error happened to me after my mac mini got un-plugged (so forced shutdown), and all I had to do to fix it was restart

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with postgres 11 on my mac. I get this error every time after restart

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory

Is the server running locally and accepting connections on 
Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

As a temporary fix I do

```
brew services stop postgresql@11
brew services start postgresql@11
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem happened after a brew update so I've ran

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start
```

and I've got this result:

```
FATAL: database files are incompatible with server 2021-07-07 13:27:21.692 CEST [70896] DETAIL: The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 12, which is not compatible with this version 13.2. stopped waiting
```

I've ran

```
brew postgresql-upgrade-database
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FATAL:  could not load server certificate file "/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem": No such file or directory
LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
```

I have a missing ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem file so i created it using **make-ssl-cert generate-default-snakeoil --force-overwrite** And it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to run journalctl -xe, and it showed that my disk was full. I then deleted some .gz items from /var/log and I could again restart the postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Kali Linux.  I had to remove the brew version of postgresql with

`brew uninstall postgresql`

`sudo -u postgres psql` got me into root postgres

Answer (score 0):

Simply running these commands from the installation steps in the official PostgreSQL docs worked for me (I'm on Fedora 33):

```sh
# Optionally initialize the database and enable automatic start:
sudo /usr/pgsql-13/bin/postgresql-13-setup initdb
sudo systemctl enable postgresql-13
sudo systemctl start postgresql-13
```

[RHEL Installation link](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/redhat/)

Answer (score 0):

kali users pls do this

*sudo service postgresql restart*

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: your postgresql service is off, use the command to start or restart the service port

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue.

I wasn't able to use `psql` also, as the service was down.
`pg_lsclusters` showed the cluster is down and I couldn't start it with `pg_ctlcluster <version> <cluster_name> start`, because "postgres was the owner".

Solved my issue with `sudo -i -u postgres service postgresql start`
(Ubuntu 20.04)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on Ubuntu 14.04 Postgres 9.4. Where when I try to start the Postgres service it was showing the below error

```
* Starting PostgreSQL 9.4 database server
* Failed to issue method call: Unit postgresql@9.4-main.service failed to load: No such file or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl status postgresql@9.4-main.service' for details.
```

I checked every answer mentioned in this thread but nothing seems working for me.

In the end, I just switch my user to **postgres** and then tried to start the service, all the postgres services started without any error.

Hope it might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.

**So i checked for the logs**

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-14-main.log (14 -> version of installed)
```

**output as below**

```
Examine the log output.
2023-04-05 19:43:16.884 +0530 [7097] FATAL:  could not open log file "/var/log/postgresql/logs/postgresql-2023-04-05.log": Permission denied
2023-04-05 19:43:16.886 +0530 [7097] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
```

**after i checked for the log file permission**

```
ls -ld /var/log/postgresql/logs
drw-r----- 2 postgres postgres 4096 Jan 29 09:18 /var/log/postgresql/logs
```

**I excuted below commands**

```
sudo chown postgres:postgres /var/log/postgresql/logs
sudo chmod 750 /var/log/postgresql/logs
sudo systemctl restart postgresql
sudo -u postgres psql
```

I was able fix the issue.