# Issue with starting postgres server on Centos 7

Tags: postgresql

I have problem with starting PostgreSQL Server on Centos 7. I installed PostgreSQL with this command: `yum install postgresql postgresql-contrib`.  Then I added a user with `sudo -i -u postgres` command. After that I'm trying to start PostgreSQL Server with `psql` command and it gives me an error:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Psql could not connect to server: No such file or directory, 5432 error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42653690/psql-could-not-connect-to-server-no-such-file-or-directory-5432-error)

Comment: `psql` does not start the server - it connects to an already running server. To start Postgres you need `service postgresql-10 start` (or something similar)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

> `psql` is a terminal-based front-end to PostgreSQL. It enables you to
>   type in queries interactively, issue them to PostgreSQL, and see the
>   query results.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pg-ctl.html

> `pg_ctl` - initialize, start, stop, or control a PostgreSQL server

(formatting mine)