# postgresql error connecting after moving data directory

Tags: database, postgresql

**EDIT-2**

I found out that the database doesn't even start after making the file location change.

This is with the default file location:

```
$pg_isready
/var/run/postgresql:5432 - accepting connections
$pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file
9.5 main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.5-main.log
```

`pg_lsclusters` output is green.

After the file location has changed on postgresql.conf:

```
$pg_isready
/var/run/postgresql:5432 - no response
$pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner Data directory                           Log file
9.5 main    5432 down   root  /mnt/Data/postgresdb/postgresql/9.5/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.5-main.log
```

Here the output is red.

Following this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42653690/psql-could-not-connect-to-server-no-such-file-or-directory-5432-error), I tried to start the cluster manually:

```
$pg_ctlcluster 9.5 main start
Warning: the cluster will not be running as a systemd service. Consider using systemctl:
  sudo systemctl start postgresql@9.5-main
Error: You must run this program as the cluster owner (root) or root
```

I tried the same command with sudo:

```
Error: Config owner (postgres:124) and data owner (root:0) do not match, and config owner is not root
```

Which again makes me think the problem might lie with permissions of the directory. The directory is owned by root whose ownership I am unable to change.

**EDIT-1**

I've been working on this and I'd like to distill this post further to give more specifics. This is my current situation:

1. I installed postgres: `sudo apt-get install postgresql and postgresql-contrib`
2. I used `sudo -U postgres psql` to get into the postgres shell (I'm not sure if this is what I need to do)
3. show data_directory returns: `/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main`

The data directory is located in Ubuntu ext4 formatted hard drive. I also have a 1 TB NTFS formatted hard disk mounted on `/mnt/Data` (which is mounted automatically on boot). What I tried:

1. Stop the postgres service: `sudo systemctl stop postgresql`
2. Create a new directory `/mnt/Data/postgresdb` and copy contents of the previous main to this which gives me a full path of `/mnt/Data/postgresdb/postgresql/9.5/main` using: `sudo rsync -av /var/lib/postgresql/ /mnt/Data/postgresdb/postgresql/`
3. Edit `/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf` to change data_directory from the path mentioned above to `/mnt/Data/postgresdb/postgresql/9.5/main`
4. Start the postgres service: `sudo systemctl start postgresl`
5. Run `sudo -U postgres psql` but get the error that was mentioned in the original post.

These are the permissions on the respective main directories:

```
        ls -l /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/
total 4.0K drwx------ 19 postgres postgres 4.0K Jan 16 12:40 main 
    ls -l /mnt/Data/postgresdb/postgresql/9.5/
total 4.0K drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4.0K Jan 16 12:13 main
```

From the looks of it, the default directory is owned by "postgres" and the new directory is owned by root. However, when I try to change ownership to postgres: `chown -R postgres main`, it doesn't output any error, but the ownership doesn't change. I'm curious whether this is because this drive is NTFS formatted and is mounted.

Here is my /etc/fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=3f5a9875-89a3-4ce5-b778-9d7aaf148ed6 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=85c3f4d4-e450-435b-8dd6-cf1b2cbd8fc2 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-label/Data /mnt/Data auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

Any ideas on how I can go about fixing this?

**ORIGINAL POST**

Recently, I installed Postgresql for storing some data for my research. The dataset came with instructions on how to setup the data on a Postgresql database (if interested, more info on that [here](https://mimic.physionet.org/tutorials/install-mimic-locally-ubuntu/) and [here](https://github.com/MIT-LCP/mimic-code)). I installed Postgresql and set up a "role" and used the script that was provided for loading the database. It worked but I underestimated the size of the dataset and the script quit saying there was no more space.

I have two drives on my computer a 250G SSD drive with Windows and Ubuntu installed (125G each). And a 1TB HDD NTFS formatted where I store my data. So I thought moving the database to a folder on the other drive would be helpful. I purged all the data and the database to start afresh and followed the instructions [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-a-postgresql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-16-04) to move the database directory. However, after moving the directory, when I try to connect using psql I get the following error:

```
 ~ psql -U username -d postgres                                                                                                                                                                   14:48:33
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

How can I fix this? I am running 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04 with Postgresql-9.5. As mentioned earlier, I moved the DB directory a NTFS formatted filesystem (not sure if that cause any problems).

Thanks.

Comment: Well, did you start the service? If not, does it start? If not, is there any error message in the Postgres logfile?

Comment: I did restart the service. I still get the same error. Where can I find the logfile?

Comment: `pg_ctl -D '/your/new/path' start` - what's the output?..

Comment: I don't have a pg_ctl command. I have pg_ctlcluster and pg_lsclusters.

Comment: I believe that the NTFS *is* causing the problem. The permissions and ownership on the NTFS volume aren't correct. That is why you get the error. The easy solution is to NOT use NTFS.

Also, you should have `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/pg_ctl` and you should mention that you are using the debian or ubuntu version of postgres, not the postgres distributed by postgres.

Comment: I am using the Ubuntu version (thats in the official repo) of Postgres (I thought I mentioned it, sorry if I didn't). So there is no workaround for this? As a final recourse I guess I could carve out some 100GB from the other HDD and format it as ext4 and host the data there..

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments the NTFS was the problem. I ended up resizing my bigger hard drive with 100GB formatted as ext4 and was able to launch postgres with the new data directory without any problems.