# Cannot find PostgreSQL files, clusters, or service; what to do?

Tags: postgresql

I am currently trying to install and setup PostreSQL on my computer (Debian 9) so I can use it as a local testing environment for Heroku. I have been having some problems. First, whenever I try to run `psql` (and similar commands), I get this error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I have looked around on here for some fixes to this, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573204/psql-could-not-connect-to-server-no-such-file-or-directory-mac-os-x), however I cannot find the `postmaster.pid` anywhere inside `/usr`. When looking for `/var/run/postgresql`, my search also turned up nothing.

Another promising answer was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42653690/psql-could-not-connect-to-server-no-such-file-or-directory-5432-error), however, I run `pg_lsclusters`, none appear. From a bit of searching, it says that this is probably due to `initdb` never being ran. I looked around for several ways to do this manually; none of them have worked or appear to exist on my system.

I have tried many of the "simple" things, such as `sudo`, `sudo su postgres`, removing and reinstalling the package <del>and screaming at the computer</del>.

What exactly is going on here? How do I fix it?

My OS (as mentioned before) is Debian 9, and the `psql --version` (which does work) is `psql (PostgreSQL) 10.4 (Debian 10.4-2.pgdg90+1)`.

Comment: be sure to install the packages `postgresql-server` and `postgresql-common`

Comment: @Jasen I installed `postgresql-common`, however installing the former results in `Package 'postgresql-server' has no installation candidate`; `psql` still doesn't work