# How to solve psql error: could not connect to server?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm trying to install GeoDjango for my website. To do that, I first need to create a PostgreSQL database. Following [this tutorial](https://tecadmin.net/install-postgresql-server-on-ubuntu/), I'm trying to connect to PostgreSQL by using `sudo su - postgres` and then `psql`. The problem is that I get this error : `psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`

I made some researchs and found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42653690/psql-could-not-connect-to-server-no-such-file-or-directory-5432-error) explaining how to solve the problem. However, when I run `sudo service postgresql start` I have to type the password for postgres but I don't know what it is, I never created a password for postgres. I've made researchs about that and I can't find a solution because all solutions need to first connect to psql in order to alter the existing user. But I need first to find the password in order to solve the problem of connection to psql.

What am I supposed to do ?

Thanks in advance !

PS : I'm using windows 10 with the Ubuntu terminal.

PS2 : I've found some topics saying it's easier to install PostgreSQL and PostGIS using Docker. However, there are lots of compatibility problems with Docker due to the fact I'm using windows 10. Do you think I should use Docker ?

Comment: what does the variable `listen_addresses` in your `postgresql.conf` look like?

Comment: The password asked by `sudo` is your current operating system user's password.

Comment: @JimJones here it is : ```#listen_addresses = 'localhost'```,   
```port = 5432 ```

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I'm talking about password for postgres, not for sudo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution !

So for those interested, I had to change the password in order to get log in and that solve the `psql error: could not connect to server`. To change the password, simply type `sudo passwd postgres` and set up a new password. I hope this will help other people !