# PostgreSQL 12 connection error in Travis CI

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci

This is my Travis YML file:

```
language: php
dist: focal

services:
  - postgresql
addons:
  postgresql: '12'
  apt:
    packages:
      - postgresql-12
      - postgresql-client-12
cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.composer/cache/files
matrix:
  fast_finish: true
  include:
    - php: 7.4
env:
  - SYMFONY_VERSION="5.*" DB=postgresql PGPORT=5432
before_install:
  - composer self-update
install:
  - composer install
  - psql -c 'create database testbase;' -U postgres
  - php ./bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --no-interaction
script:
  - phpunit
```

And during the build, on this line:

```
$ psql -c 'create database testbase;' -U postgres
```

I am getting this error:

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
The command "psql -c 'create database testbase;' -U postgres" failed and exited with 2 during .
```

I also tried versions of PostgreSQL 11 and 10, but same error. When I switch build distribution to xenial from focal, build and tests will pass. But our production server is focal, so that can't be our solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42653690

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12472988/

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/285080

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/50621

Comment: @RobertHarvey Please read the first line of the question, it's nothing local neither I have access to the server. Travis CI is hosted CI service for more information you can find here. travis-ci.com

Comment: I'm not going to check the Travis CI site.  My point is that there's a lot of prior art here.  What have you tried?

Comment: Everything I can do is in this `.travis.yml` file. When I switch build distribution to xenial from focal, build and tests will pass. But our production server is focal, so I need a solution for why Travis CI focal distribution has issues with PostgreSQL 12. Similar issues had a bionic version with PostgreSQL 9. But as I remember Travis team fixed that more than one year ago.

Comment: Put that information into your question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey these questions are not duplicates, we're talking about 3rd party which is mutable changing state since all previous answers :)

tldr: faced the same issue, changed switch build from focal to xenial and it starts connection. I suspect in focal they put postgresql's socket somewhere else. Sad, but SO became travis' issue tracker

Comment: I never said they were duplicates.