# Postgresql: Cannot connect to server after computer restart

Tags: postgresql, macos, server, homebrew

I'm running macOS Monterey version 12.2.

After restarting my laptop I can no longer connect to my postgresql server. and am getting this error:

```
(base) user@user Application Support % brew services restart postgresql
Stopping `postgresql`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `postgresql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql)
==> Successfully started `postgresql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql)
(base) user@user Application Support % psql postgres
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

I found may suggestions online such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42653690/psql-could-not-connect-to-server-no-such-file-or-directory-5432-error) to remove `postmaster.pid`. I could not find `postmaster.pid` in the suggested path (`/usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid`) however I did find a `postmaster.pid`under `/usr/local/var/postgres.backup/postmaster.pid` which I then removed. but I am still getting the same error.

Can anyone help me with this? And can anyone help clarify why I had no `/usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid` but did have a `/usr/local/var/postgres.backup/postmaster.pid`?

Comment: Is the postgres DB running on Docker? or directly installed on your machine?

Comment: @ManuManjunath  it's directly installed on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. Postgres stopped working after restarting my computer. If you use brew, you can try `brew services restart postgresql` but that did not work either.

These commands work for me:

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop
```

Then `start`

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start
```

You can also check status with `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres status`